# Codeigniter - Jquery validation not working on specific page for mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using jquery validation plugin with CodeIgniter for some reason the jquery gets submitted before the validation on the register page only for mobile. login page works perfectly with the same code. I have attached the code here.

Register-validation.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$.validator.setDefaults({
    errorClass: 'text-danger',
    highlight: function(element) {
        $(element)
            .closest('.form-group')
            .addClass('has-error');
    },
    unhighlight: function(element) {
        $(element)
            .closest('.form-group')
            .removeClass('has-error')
            .addClass('has-success');
    },

    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        if (element.attr("type") === "checkbox") {
            error.appendTo(element.parent().parent());
        } else {
            error.insertAfter(element);
        }
    }
});

$.validator.addMethod('strongPassword', function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) ||
        value.length >= 8 &&
        /\d/.test(value) &&
        /[a-z]/i.test(value);
}, 'Your password must be 8 characters long and contain atleast one number and character ')

$("#form-register").validate({
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        $.ajax({
            url: base_url + 'users/register',
            type: "POST",
            data: $(form).serialize(),
            dataType: "JSON",
            beforeSend: function() {
                $(window).scrollTop(0);
                $("#show-progress").addClass('progress');
            },
            success: function(feedback) {
                if (feedback['error'] == "success") {
                    window.location.href = feedback.message;
                }
            }


        });
    },

    rules: {
        fname: {
            required: true,
            lettersonly: true
        },
        lname: {
            required: true,
            lettersonly: true
        },
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true,
            remote: {
                url: base_url + 'users/checkEmailExists',
                type: "post"

            }
        },

        dob: {
            required: true
        },

        username: {
            required: true,
            alphanumeric: true,
            minlength: 6,
            remote: {
                url: base_url + 'users/checkUsernameExists',
                type: "post"

            }
        },

        mobile: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 10,
            maxlength: 10,
            number: true,
            remote: {
                url: base_url + 'users/checkMobileExists',
                type: "post"

            }

        },
        password: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 8,
            strongPassword: true
        },
        confirm_password: {
            required: true,
            equalTo: "#password"
        },
        terms: {
            required: true
        }
    },



    messages: {

        fname : {
            lettersonly: 'Enter a valid name'
        },

        lname : {
            lettersonly: 'Enter a valid name'
        },

        email: {
            email: 'Please enter a valid email address',
            remote: $.validator.format("{0} is associated with an account, choose a different email")

        },

        terms: {
            required: 'Agree to the terms of use'
        },

        mobile: {
            minlength: 'Enter a valid mobile number eg: 07XXXXXXXX',
            maxlength: 'Enter a valid mobile number eg: 07XXXXXXXX',
            remote: $.validator.format("{0} is associated with an account, choose a different mobile")
        },

        username: {
            alphanumeric: 'Username can only contain letters, numbers and underscore',
            remote: $.validator.format("{0} is already taken, choose a different username")

        }
    }


});

});
```

Register.php

```
    <!-- –––––––––––––––[ PAGE CONTENT ]––––––––––––––– -->
    <main id="mainContent" class="main-content">

        <div class="page-container ptb-60">
        <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>

        <div class="container">
            <div id="show-progress"></div>
                <section class="panel p-40">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                             <h2 class="h3 mb-20 h-title">Register New Profile  <small>Or <a href="<?php echo base_url()?>users/login" class="color-green">Log in</a></small></h2>
                         <?php echo form_open('users/register', 'class="p-40" id="form-register"');?>

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>First Name</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" name="fname" id="fname">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Last Name</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" name="lname" id="lname">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Email</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id="email" name="email" id="email"> 
                                </div> 
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label >Mobile</label>
                                    <input type="number" class="form-control input-lg" name="mobile" id="mobile">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label >Date of Birth</label>
                                    <input id="dob" class="form-control input-lg" type="text" name="dob" style="background-color:#fff;" data-altinput="true" data-altFormat="F j, Y">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                <label >Gender</label>
                                     <div class="custom-radio">
                                        <input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender1" value="M" checked><label class="color-mid" for="gender1">Male</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="custom-radio">
                                        <input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender2" value="F"><label class="color-mid" for="gender2">Female</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Username</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" name="username" id="username">

                                </div>                                    
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label >Password</label>
                                    <input type="password" class="form-control input-lg" name="password" id="password">

                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label >Confirm Password</label>
                                    <input type="password" class="form-control input-lg" name="confirm_password" id="password-confirm">

                                </div>
                                 <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="custom-checkbox mb-20">
                                        <input type="checkbox" id="agree_terms" name="terms">
                                        <label class="color-mid terms" for="agree_terms">I agree to the <a href="<?php echo base_url()?>terms" class="color-green">Terms of Use</a> and <a href="<?php echo base_url()?>privacy" class="color-green">Privacy Statement</a>.</label>
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-lg" id="btn-register">Register</button>
                            <?php echo form_close(); ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
    <!--–––––––––––––––[ END PAGE CONTENT ]–––––––––––––––-->
```

The form gets submitted in mobile view. but when I try to type anything in the fields the validation works and once again if I click the submit button without validating completely the form gets submitted. please help!

Comment: Can u send the jsfiddle demo? Happy to help you.

Comment: Show us the actual **RENDERED** HTML markup as sent to the browser, NOT the PHP... JavaScript does not read PHP!

Comment: It would make more sense to show us the PHP function at `checkMobileExists`, since that has a direct impact on how the plugin's `remote` method operates.